# How to pass literal parameter to included js?

Tags: javascript, php, literals

How to pass literal parameter like `{$currchoice.id}` to js?
I have the following currency selector, I need to pass its selected value to javascript as param in `(currency=2)` to be `(currency={$currchoice.id})`

```
    <!-- Currency -->
   {if !$loggedin && count($currencies) > 1}
       <div class="pull-right nav">
           <a href="#" class="quick-nav" data-toggle="popover" id="currencyChooser"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i> {$LANG.choosecurrency} <span class="caret"></span></a>
           <div id="currencyChooserContent" class="hidden">
               {foreach from=$currencies item=currchoice}
                   <img src="{$BASE_PATH_IMG}/flags/{$currchoice.code|substr:0:2|strtolower}.png"> <a href="{$currentpagelinkback}currency={$currchoice.id}">{if $currency.id eq $currchoice.id}<u>{/if}{$currchoice.code}</u></a>
               {/foreach}
           </div>
       </div>
   {/if}

<script language="javascript" src="feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=1&get=price&billingcycle=monthly&currency=2"></script>
```

Comment: And when you replace `2` with `{$currchoice.id}` what happens?

Comment: I tried but with no effect

Comment: "no effect" really doesn't tell much. Look in the compiled source and see what it shows there.

Comment: Have you tried data attributes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes ?

Comment: `<script language="javascript" src="feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=1&get=price&billingcycle=monthly&currency={$currchoice.id}"></script>`

Results ` “https://belocloud.com/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=1&get=price&billingcycle=monthly&currency=” `

`<script language="javascript" src="feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=1&get=price&billingcycle=monthly&currency={$currchoice.id}"></script>`

Results The script from ` “https://belocloud.com/feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=1&get=price&billingcycle=monthly&currency=%27%27”' was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a `popover`-menu which users can select a currency in, then you ask how to add another script, based on the users choice.

Well if you prefer refreshing the page, simply pass URL-parameter from controller to view, something like:

```php
public function getMyView($request) {
    // TODO: replace 0 with your default currency-id.
    return view('path.to.view')
        ->with('selectedCurrency', $request->input('currency') ?? 0)
}
```

And use that in view, like:

```
<script language="javascript" src="feeds/productsinfo.php?pid=1&get=price&billingcycle=monthly&currency={{$selectedCurrency}}"></script>
```

---

But if you don't want to refresh on each user click, then:

- Remove the `<script ...` thing entirely from your view.
- Add `JQuery` code (or something like that) to find the selected value (e.g. currency id).
- Then at last, add `script`-element dynamically using `JavaScript`.

> **Note** that the second approach requires your entire JS (and what depends on it) to support lazy loading (without causing errors).